# Tagging users in Wordpress

Tags: users, tags, user-roles

I have a community blog at thelazy.info . I want to tag users based on their colleges and assign a role known as "College Owner" which will have permissions to edit users belonging to his colleges. How can I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has no multi-level user and group ownerships / permissions by default. So what you are asking for you need to implement on your own by extending the database and the program.

You can then fine-grained control what users are allowed to do and what not. Like Zack suggested, this can be combined with custom user profile fields, but you can do anything you like with a system of your own.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the following article. I think it's what you want.

- [Adding and using custom user profile fields](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can tag users using the get/add_option function; each option is concidered a tag and its value is the users id's array

Answer (score 0):

For tagging you can use the [User Tags Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-tags/), while for managing the users forsame tag, you have to go for a custom script, the plugin will make it easier as it uses WordPress taxonomy for tagging